# Crystal Reports Grouping

Tags: crystal-reports

My data looks like this.

```
Fruit, Apple, Fuji, 1, 1
Vegetable, Potato, Russett, 2, 2
Fruit, Apple, Red, 1, 3
Fruit, Apple, Granny, 1, 2
Vegetable, Potato, White, 2, 1
```

This data is not sorted beforehand.

I have every field in a group (say Group1, Group2, 3, 4, and 5).  I would like for the data to read like this.

I've creates a group combining the fields 4 and 5 using a formula.

The problem is when I drop my cross tab into Group 5 it keeps repeating the column header.  Whereas, if I drop into Group 4 it does not repeat the column header.  However, it does not sort on Field 5.

I would think there is some easy way around this.

TIA.

Name

Comment: What groups are for what fields?

Comment: Group 4 is for Field 4.  Group 5 is Field 4 + Field 5.

Comment: why there are 5 groups? What sorting are you looking for? what you want to show in group 4 and what you want to show in group 5? finally what is the report requirement?